# I want to receive video frame data (an image) in C# client from python socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, video-encoding, python-sockets

I have created python socket server. Where on server i process video data. When one frame of video is processed i want to show it on C# client.
So i create a C# client but i don't know how to sent and receive the data.

My current code is ...
python Server side

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('connected to : ' + addr[0] +" :"+ str(addr[1])) 

    videoPath = './Videos/abc.mp4'

    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    total_frames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    conn.setblocking(0)
    for mm in range(0,total_frames ,1):
       #vidcap.set(1, mm)
       try:
           dataClient = str(conn.recv(4096).decode('UTF-8'))
           conn.send(str.encode(dataClient))   
           conn.close()
           kk=2
           break
       except socket.error:
           #print (socket.EWOULDBLOCK)
           ret,img= vidcap.read()
           image = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480)) 

           data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
           conn.send(data)
```

this is client on C#

```
            int PORT_NO = 6666;
            //const string SERVER_IP = "210.107.232.138"; // 210.107.232.138          127.0.0.1
            string SERVER_IP = IpAddress.Text;
            client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);

            nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(videoPath.ToString());
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Coneected ...........");



 private void My_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


                bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0,client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                Stream imageStreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytesRead);

                Image iimage = Image.FromStream(imageStreamSource);
                pictureBox2.Image = iimage;




        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: [Microsoft's Socket Code Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples)

Comment: I like john link.  Recommend the msdn code a lot.  But it will not work with your encoding.  Never encode binary data using ASCII Encoding.  Ascii Encoding removed non printable characters.  See python documentation : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm.  There is no reason to encode/decode data on tcp.  So do not use videoPath.ToString().  You have a nwStream so just send the bytes from the stream and precede with the byte count as you have in you code.

Comment: dear @jdweng i actually i have 640x480x3 image when i convert it to byte array it is too long so therefore i need to encoded it first and decode it again. and video path sent for just testing that it is receive on server or not. Because i try without encoding the client side become hang

Comment: Encoding is not the answer.  It will slow the application down even further.  The hanging is a different issue.  Either you need to convert the image to a different image format that uses less memory or you need use a stream as an interface.

Comment: My problem is that i have python program. which do some operation on video frames. Like for each frame it detect some object and draw a bonding box around this object on that frame. Now i need to display this processed frame on C# window form. I don't know how it is possible. i think one solution is to sent this processed frame to C# using socket. But i am getting  problems. if you know any solution with other protocol or possible for that problem i will try that. please me guide me.

Comment: I need just to sent this image either it is encoded or without encoding. But as it is video and it will be shown as video on C# so i need to take care about the timing also.